# Publish Azure Apps in SharePoint

Tags: sharepoint-addin, azure, sso

I'm pretty inexperienced in the field of SharePoint, but among countless questions, this is one I could not find a clear answer for:

Can anyone point me in the right direction (or tell me how) for publishing apps that are accessible on the Azure App portal in SharePoint?

A customer of ours would like to use the functionality of the Azure App portal (SSO and such) from a SharePoint site.

I know how to make a SharePoint site available in the Azure App portal, but this is the other way around.

Many thanks in advance!

Comment: Are you trying to replicate the functionality of myapplications.microsoft.com, office.com, as well as the waffle?

SSO is not the domain of SharePoint. You integrate SSO with Azure first then you can expose a link to your application.

Remember, SharePoint is _not_ an IdP.

Comment: Hi Trevor,
I would like to have a link in Sharepoint for the applications I created in myapplications.microsoft.com, so users don't have to log in the myapplications portal to access these. But they can still benefit from the SSO that I associated with the app.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on your last comment, you simply need to grab the URL for each application. You can get the URL from the three vertical dots for each tile in My Applications and Copy Link.

Paste that link into SharePoint.

I would suggest that there isn't much benefit to doing so as all of the applications are in the App Launcher in the upper left of most M365 services, including SPO.

Comment: That was exactly what I was looking for. Should have thought of that myself.
Thanks Trevor!